# Dynamically display text in Flex, ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, text, actionscript

I've been having problems displaying text in ActionScript 3 using Flex SDK 4.6. Any method I try results in no change or a black screen; here is my project code and attempts.

MyProject.mxml is simply and `mx:Application` tag with the relevant parts being

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  include "MyProject.as"; //simply running my project file
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

and

```
<mx:Canvas id="gamePanel" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/> //defining the canvas
```

In MyProject.as I have

```
import flash.display.*; 
import flash.events.*;
import mx.events.*;
import mx.controls.*;

import Game;

public static const SCREEN_WIDTH:int = 960;
public static const SCREEN_HEIGHT:int = 720;
private var initializationCompleted:Boolean = false;
public var screenBuffer:BitmapData;
public var game:Game;

public function setup():void {
    screenBuffer = new BitmapData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, false, 0x00000000);
    game = new Game(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, screenBuffer);
    initializationCompleted = true;
}

private function updateFrame():void {
    if (!initializationCompleted) {
        return;
    }

    draw();

    gamePanel.graphics.clear();
    gamePanel.graphics.beginBitmapFill(screenBuffer, null, false, false);
    gamePanel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    gamePanel.graphics.endFill();
}

private function draw():void {
    game.update();
}
```

And in Game.as, I simply draw everything using the BitmapData class, and then copy everything to the screenBuffer:

```
screenBuffer.copyPixels(myBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), new Point(0,0));
```

(This is only the relevant code - I trimmed as much as possible to leave a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example")

Now I have been having problems displaying text in my project. I know that `TextField` is a subclass of `flash.display.Sprite` which can be added to the canvas. Whenever I try using something like

```
var txtHello:TextField = new TextField();
txtHello.text = "Hello World";
gamePanel.addChild(txtHello)
```

this either changes nothing (if used in `setup()`, I'm assuming I'm drawing over it or else it is never displayed) or causes a black screen (if used anywhere in `updateFrame()`, I'm assuming I'm creating infinite sprites).

I have tried instead, creating a new file named "TextWithImage.as" with the contents

```
//this is ripped off the adobe help page
package { 
    import flash.display.Sprite; 
    import flash.text.*; 

    public class TextWithImage extends Sprite { 
        private var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField(); 
        private var myText:String = "Hello World"; 

        public function TextWithImage() { 
            addChild(myTextBox); 
            myTextBox.text = myText; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

importing it in MyProject.as, and then using it as

```
gamePanel.addChild(new TextWithImage());
```

to the same effect as my previous attempt.

What is the simplest way to display text in Flex/AS3? Any help is appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick. Flex components, albeit having the same **addChild** method derived from **DisplayObjectContainer** class, cannot actually add regular Flash content - Shape, Sprite, MovieClip, TextField, Bitmap - directly. More to that, they don't produce any runtime error, which I personally think they totally could to not confuse new people.

Flex component can only **addChild** classes that extend the basic **UIComponent** class.  At the same time, **UIComponent** can **addChild** regular Flash content. Thus you do it as following:

```
var proxyContainer:UIComponent = new UIComponent;
var txtHello:TextField = new TextField;

txtHello.text = "Hello World";
proxyContainer.addChild(txtHello);

gamePanel.addChild(proxyContainer);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.